# How to get Facebook Post Like Count given FB Post ID via PHP or WordPress

Tags: php, facebook, wordpress, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am trying to get the like count of some Facebook Posts (not pages). I am confused by all the options to get that data, and none of the options I've tried work. I'm not sure if I can get a like count directly by a URL, Facebook Graph API, FQL, or what, or whether I have to count up the likes, and so on. I am also not clear if I need to use an access_token or something else, and if so, how?

I have a WordPress plugin that has pulled in some data on Facebook Posts. I have the URL and IDs of these posts, e.g., https://www.facebook.com/merchantguru/posts/170475449629957 or 154533921224110_170475449629957

So, to clarify my question: using PHP (WordPress), how do I pull a Facebook Post like count given its URL or ID?

P.S. I am BRAND NEW to Facebook programming,have read a number of stackoverflow Q&A's, googled, perused Facebook Developer documentation and tools, and I still can't figure it out. Also note, I'm looking for Post  Like counts not Page Like counts.

Comment: Isn't the like count one of the top-level fields of the post? so just accessing `https://graph.facebook.com/<POST ID HERE>?access_token=<USER ACCESS TOKEN>` should return the like count in the 'likes' field? - For the example post you have there, i see: in the likes field the 4 users who like it, followed by `"count": 4`

Comment: I don't see "count": 4. Can you clarify if I have my URL correct, I'm using: `https://graph.facebook.com/154533921224110_170475449629957?access_token=CAAH9Nqobvgw....` and I'm using my personal access token. I'm not sure if that's correct or how to get a proper access token.

Comment: To clarify, the access token is from the Facebook App I created to link with my WordPress site. So, still wondering if I'm using the correct access_token, whether my URL is correct, and how to get the like count (a ton of other data shows, including the likes, but not the count).

Comment: Using `fields=likes.summary‌​(true)` works. Not sure why I don't get `"count":4` at the top-level per @lgy. Nonetheless, this works. Now I need to figure out how to parse json in WordPress. `https://graph.facebook.com/154533921224110_170475449629957?fields=likes.summary(true)&access_token=CAAH9NqobvgwBAKV3uMMjryhn8yyMVGNrEG6Xpb0zlCxs5yDYzJGxvM4ZBpwi1bpW25C6ca7L8u5Coo8ngsy9c3RQCssnScXoS9byZBcsgTjyntTbvJdbgb1CYRAT1C5zoJTbng9BGVTxnv5kYI`

Answer (score 0):

Here is something you can do using facebook FQL:

```
$Posts = 'SELECT like_info from stream WHERE post_id="154533921224110_170475449629957" ';
$ret_Posts = $facebook->api(array('method' => 'fql.query','query' => $Posts));
echo $ret_Posts[0]['like_info']['like_count'];
```